# Construct a self-dual binary linear code of length 8

Tags: coding-theory

I need to construct a self-duel linear binary code of length 8.

So I know that a self duel code is one such that $C = C^{\bot}$. That is, I need to find a code of length 8 that has a generator matrix for $C$ that is also a check matrix for $C$. However, i'm stuck as to how to proceed in finding the matrix.

Comment: You need to find four linearly independent binary vectors of length 8 that are orthogonal to each other and to themselves. Here: two vectors are orthogonal if they have an even number of common $1$s. So for example $11000000$ and $00110000$ are orthogonal to themselves (even number of $1$s) and to each other (no shared $1$). They are also linearly independent, because if you use them as rows of a matrix that matrix is already in reduced row echelon form. Can you find a set of four such vectors?

Comment: Actually there is more interesting (in comparison to the one I hinted at above) self-dual code of length 8 that has minimum distance four. Look up extended Hamming codes.